# Parsing variable into .get() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

:-)

I cannot get this to work!

The variable "textpageId" won't work inside the .get() function?
How do i parse an id in to the function then??

```
            var textpageId = $(this).attr("textPageID");
        if (isOpen != true) {
            console.log("Clicked");
            $.get("@Url.Action("Index", "Upload", new { textId = textpageId })", function (data) {
                console.log(data);
```

Comment: You need to understand that template is processed on the server side, and you are trying to use client side variable there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concatenate the variable inside url using plus ( + ) signs, see below code -

**NOTE** - are `Index` and `Upload` variables? If yes, then concatenate them in same way as did for `textpageId`.

```
var textpageId = $(this).attr("textPageID");
if (isOpen != true) {
     console.log("Clicked");
     $.get("@Url.Action("Index", "Upload", new { textId = " + textpageId + "})", function (data) {
          console.log(data);
```

Comment: Hello. And thanks for your reply. :-)

I have been doing a lot of reading myself. Would it be better practice for me to use the data : {} parameter in the jquery.get() where i use the url?

And no., The Index and Upload are Controller(Upload) and Action(Index) :-)

Regards

Comment: I meant the data : {} parameter in jquery.ajax(). :-)